# Java - How to Debug Task<Void>?

Tags: java, debugging, exception

I have a long running `Task` in my project that I am having a hard time debugging. As I understand it, the `Task` will never throw an exception, nor allow any of the code within it to do so.

While testing the application, I am running into many situations where the execution just hangs, no errors, no warnings, nothing.

Now, I have been able to catch `Throwable` instead to see what is causing the problem, but this seems like a poor idea and is creating a lot more work than necessary.

So my question is, as an amateur programmer, how should I go about debugging the code in my Task when I can't see exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Some methods:

1) Show enough logs (eg: `System.out`, `logback`, `log4j2`)

```
void taskMethod() {
    System.out.println("Tip1");
    doSomething1();
    System.out.println("Tip2");
    doSomething2();
    System.out.println("task over");
}
```

2) When the task hangs without exiting, you can use `jstack` to show the stack to see where the task hangs.

3) Use an IDE like `Intellij IDEA` or `Eclipse`, when debugging the program and it hangs, just click 'Break' or 'Pause' in the debug toolbar, then you have a chance to debug into the program.